# Vulkan: Image error when recreating the swapchain after a window resize

Tags: c++, vulkan

So I'm trying to handle window resizing by recreating the swapchain and its image views and all that. This is the method that I'm using:

```
void VxRenderer::recreateSwapchain() {
    device.waitIdle();

    for (uint32_t i = 0; i < swapchainImageCount; ++i) {
        vkDestroyFramebuffer(device, framebuffers[i], nullptr);
        vkDestroyImageView(device, swapchainImageViews[i], nullptr);
    }

    vkResetCommandPool(device, commandPool, 0);
    vkDestroyPipeline(device, pipeline, nullptr);
    vkDestroySwapchainKHR(device, swapchain, nullptr);

    createSwapchain();
    getSwapchainImages();
    createSwapchainImageViews();
    createFramebuffers();
    createGraphicsPipeline();
    recordCommandBuffers();
}
```

The problem is that **sometimes** I get this error when resizing:

```
Validation Error: [ VUID-VkPresentInfoKHR-pImageIndices-01296 ] Object 0: handle = 0x1d7260c6cc8,
type = VK_OBJECT_TYPE_QUEUE; | MessageID = 0xc7aabc16 | vkQueuePresentKHR(): pSwapchains[0] images
passed to present must be in layout VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_PRESENT_SRC_KHR or VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_SHARED_PRESENT_KHR
but is in VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_UNDEFINED. The Vulkan spec states: Each element of pImageIndices must be the
index of a presentable image acquired from the swapchain specified by the corresponding element of the
pSwapchains array, and the presented image subresource must be in the VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_PRESENT_SRC_KHR
layout at the time the operation is executed on a VkDevice
(https://github.com/KhronosGroup/Vulkan-Docs/search?q=)VUID-VkPresentInfoKHR-pImageIndices-01296)
```

It says that the problem comes from the elements in `pImageIndices` in the `VkPresentInfoKHR` structure, which I wrote as:

```
uint32_t imageIndex;
VkResult result =
        vkAcquireNextImageKHR(device, swapchain, UINT64_MAX, imageAcquiredSemaphores[currentImage], VK_NULL_HANDLE, &imageIndex);

if (result == VK_ERROR_OUT_OF_DATE_KHR) {
    recreateSwapchain();
    return;
}

...

VkPresentInfoKHR presentInfo;
presentInfo.sType              = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_PRESENT_INFO_KHR;
presentInfo.pNext              = nullptr;
presentInfo.waitSemaphoreCount = 1;
presentInfo.pWaitSemaphores    = &renderFinishedSemaphores[currentImage];
presentInfo.swapchainCount     = 1;
presentInfo.pSwapchains        = &swapchain;
presentInfo.pImageIndices      = &imageIndex;
presentInfo.pResults           = nullptr;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to transfer your image from the undefined layout in which it starts to a presentable image format, depending on what exactly you're doing with it. For example, if you're using it as a texture in a shader, it needs to be in `SHADER_READ_ONLY_OPTIMAL` layout.

You can do this in multiple ways, one of them being an [image memory barrier](https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.2-extensions/man/html/VkImageMemoryBarrier.html) that you can [submit](https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.2-extensions/man/html/vkCmdPipelineBarrier.html) to a transient queue. And you absolutely need to do this after recreating your swap chain, because your entire context is invalidated by the window resize operation.

Comment: Do you know why this only happens sometimes? Because I certain situations everything keeps going like nothing bad happened.

Comment: That's like asking why you can still read memory sometimes after you free it in C. Undefined behavior is undefined behavior, and that's especially bad with a low level API like Vulkan.